# Tizen Background Vibration

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-gear-s2

I'm developing the application for Samsung Gear S2 (web) with a timer that vibrates when time ends. What I need to do so my application can vibrate even if it's in background mode?

Answer (score 1):

In general, background vibration (from screen off state) is not directly available for web apps unless you are using Alarm API or Notification.

But a timed background vibration can be easily tricked out using [Power API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/device-settings-and-systems/power-states) and [web workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp).I am sharing a sample code:

main.js

```
   window.onload = function() {
       document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
           if (e.keyName === "back") {
               try {
                   tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().hide();
               }catch (ignore) {}
           }
        });

        var mainPage = document.querySelector('#main');
        mainPage.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var contentText = document.querySelector('#content-text');


        var worker;                             //web worker
        worker = new Worker("js/worker.js");    //load from directory

        worker.onmessage = function(event) {    //receive data from worker
            tizen.power.turnScreenOn();        // forcefully turn the screen on
            setTimeout(function (){
                contentText.innerHTML = event.data;  // time counter
                navigator.vibrate(1000);
            }, 500);                          // just being safe (vibrate after screen is on)
        };

    });
};
```

worker.js

```
var i=0;

function timedCount() {
    i=i+1;
    postMessage(i);                     //send data   
    setTimeout("timedCount()",5000);    // set vibration interval (or use specific time)
}

timedCount();
```

add these lines on your config.xml

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/power"/>
<tizen:setting background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"/>
```

Once background-support is enabled the app would response while minimized, when you are applying web workers. Using **getCurrentApplication().hide()** instead of getCurrentApplication().exit() on back key event would do the task for you.

Check [Vibration Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/device/vibration) for different types of vibration.

Comment: Thank you! How can I use it to open my app (on last window) if it was minimized?